# How to count number of conversations in an email chain from Gmail atom feed

Tags: ruby, xml, email, gmail, atom-feed

Is there a way to count the number of conversations that make up an email chain in Gmail?
The XML feed returns only one entry for an email chain consisting of multiple individual emails.

So for example if I have 3 emails sent by the same email address with the same subject line, the three emails are all clubbed together to be displayed as one email giving me an incorrect count of 1.

Things i have tried -

1) Disabled - conversation view from email settings

2) Used ruby gem `gmail` which does actually count individual emails but i cannot filter by Time only by Date, which is an absolute must for me (as i would be checking for new emails every one hour)

Can any one suggest a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the [gmail gem](https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail) is hardcoded to use dates only.  You can possibly make it work if you fork it and make these modifications.

In lib/gmail.rb, add a `to_imap_datetime` method:

```
class Object
  def to_imap_date
    Date.parse(to_s).strftime("%d-%B-%Y")
  end

  def to_imap_datetime
    Time.parse(to_s).strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M %z")
  end
end
```

In lib/gmail/mailbox.rb, in the `emails` method, change the calls from `to_imap_date` to `to_imap_datetime`.

Now you should be able to do this:

```
gmail.inbox.count(:after => 1.hour.ago)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I cannot make the changes to the gem(do not have access to machines). But this is a good answer, will mark it as the solution in sometime if I do not get any other answers. Thanks again.

Comment: You don't necessarily need access to the machines - you can fork a new github project and add a Gemfile entry to have Bundler pull and use your forked repo instead of rubygems repo.  If you don't have gem install rights this won't work, unfortunately.